MoviePy: Error when saving video with audio enabled
I'm trying to use MoviePy to process a video file, detect scenes, and save subclips. Everything works fine when I disable audio (audio=False in write_videofile), but when I enable audio, I get the following error:
MoviePy - Writing video new1.mp4
MoviePy - Done !
MoviePy - video ready new1.mp4
Proc not detected chunk: 0%| | 0/388 [00:00<?, ?it/s, now=None]
MoviePy - Writing audio in new2TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):

MoviePy - Writing audio in new2TEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ahmadnaser/PycharmProjects/Sawt/Frame Detection.py", line 19, in <module>
    SubClip.write_videofile(OutputClip)

Here’s the code I’m using:
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.tools.cuts import detect_scenes

# Load the video and subclip for faster processing
clip = VideoFileClip("/Users/ahmadnaser/Documents/podcast1.mp4").subclip(0, 30)  # Process first 30 seconds
fps = clip.fps

# Detect scenes
SceneTimes = detect_scenes(clip, logger="bar", fps=fps)
FrameChangeTimes = [(float(start), float(end)) for start, end in SceneTimes[0]]

# Process subclips
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(FrameChangeTimes):
    if end - start < 3:  # Skip very short clips
        continue

    SubClip = clip.subclip(start, end)
    OutputClip = f"new{i+1}.mp4"

    # Write the subclip
    SubClip.write_videofile(OutputClip, audio=True)  # Error occurs when audio=True
    SubClip.close()

# Close the main clip
clip.close()


What I’ve Tried

Setting audio=False works, but I need the audio in the output videos.
I verified that ffmpeg is installed and works. Running ffmpeg -version confirms it's available.
The source video has an audio stream, confirmed with ffprobe.

Environment

Python version: 3.9
MoviePy version: 1.0.3
Operating system: macOS

Question
Why does enabling audio in write_videofile cause this error, and how can I fix it? Is there a specific issue with my code or setup? Any help would be appreciated.
